# How to get variables from one method to another ? How to get int x from assuming into void add()?

Tags: java

I want to pass value of x and y into method add()
Public class arithmetic {

```
public static void assuming(){ 

System.out.println("Please insert the first number");
Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = read.nextInt();

System.out.println("Please insert the second number");
Scanner read1 = new Scanner(System.in);
int y = read1.nextInt();
}


void add()
{
// How to get values of int x and int y from upper method in here ?
}
```

Comment: As x, y are primitive type, you can pass by value `void add(int x, int y)` while invoking.

Comment: create a function call `add(x,y);`

Comment: The question (title) is not clear at all, though the code shows basic problems such as calling from static method a instance method and so on...

Comment: I'm new to programming.. So

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a methdd call `add(x,y);` in assuming method.

```
int answer = add(x,y);
```

After that modify your `add` function

```
int add(int x,int y)
{
   return x+y;
}
```